# Is there a python function for calculating time-step pairs of a particular variable in an array?

Tags: python, numpy, time, python-xarray

I have an xarray object with time as a dimension, and temperature as a variable. I need to look at time-step pairs of the temperature, and calculate the difference between the two. So, for example:

```
time = [00:00:00, 00:00:01, 00:00:02, 00:00:03, 00:00:04]
temperature = [70.0, 72.0, 81.1, 67.4, 85.6]
```

The first time-step pair would be from 00:00:00 to 00:00:01. The corresponding temperatures for those time-steps are 70.0 and 72.0. So, 72.0-70.0 = 2 degrees. This pattern would need to continue throughout the entirety of the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in the temperature delta you could do this

```
import numpy as np
temperature = [70.0, 72.0, 81.1, 67.4, 85.6]
nptemp = np.array(temperature)
diff = nptemp[1:] - nptemp[:-1]
print(diff)
```

Which prints

```
[  2.    9.1 -13.7  18.2]
```

Cheers!